# Подписка по e-mail

Tags: поддержка

Или я туплю невероятно, или что-то не так. Где подписка? На ХК как-то автоматом приходили комментарии и ответы для вопросов, на которые отвечал или которые комментировал. Здесь уже всё перекопал - не вижу :( Только какие-то фильтры и подписки, с которыми вообще непонятно что делать для достижения желаемого.

Вот только при составлении вопроса заметил чекбокс "**Отправлять новые ответы на мои сообщения по почте**", да и то в лучшем случае - *каждые 3 часа*...

Answer (score 4):

Моментального уведомления по почте на Stack Overflow нет. Так как количество вопросов, ответов, комментариев и прочих событий на большом Stack Overflow невероятно велико, то, полагаю, возникают проблемы, если спамить каждому юзеру по каждому поводу.

Вместо этого, если вы в течение 3 часов не посещали сайт, то вам будет отправлено письмо со всеми произошедшими за этот период событиями, относящимися непосредственно к вам: ответы на ваши вопросы, комментарии к вашим постам, комментарии, в которых вас упомянули, и т.п.

Если хотите постоянно быть в курсе и не пропустить ничего, то можете держать страницу сайта (любого сайта из сети SE) открытой. Все уведомления будут отображены в меню сверху.

Уведомлений о комментариях к чужим ответам, о чужих ответах на вопрос, на которой ответили вы, и прочем таком — нет. И это не баг, а фича. Меня на ХК раздражал выбор: или подписываешься на все события по вопросу и получаешь по почте тонну спама, или не подписываешься и рискуешь пропустить даже то, что адресовано тебе.

Если хотите получить больше информации о каком-то вопросе, то можете добавить его в избранное. В этом случае на вкладке избранного в вашем профиле будут отображаться обновления, если произошли следующие события: редактирование вопроса или ответа, добавление ответа.

Comment: "Моментального уведомления по почте на Stack Overflow нет" - нет повести печальнее на свете... Ну вот вижу сейчас "3 вопроса с изменениями". А какие вопросы, с какими изменениями, где их искать? Да и пыриться в браузер постоянно - зачем? Он у меня вообще в трей свёрнут обычно пока не понадобится явно. В почте хоть понятно было стоит ли по ссылке тыкаться, или прочитал письмо, удалил и забыл.

Comment: @klopp, когда вы нажмете на эту строчку, вопросы с изменениями будут отображены в начале списка вопросов.

Comment: Как я уже понял, 1) в любом случае самих изменений я не увижу (это может быть и 100 бессмысленных/неинтересных комментариев, ради которых открывать страницу с вопросом смысла нет) 2) это будут изменения в вопросах, интереса к которым я не проявлял (то есть не отвечал, не комментировал и не подписывался явно).

Answer (score 4):

Ещё один мощный инструмент подписки на уведомления на сайтах сети Stack Exchange - ленты RSS. Такие сводки формируются для вопросов с главной страницы, для вопросов с определённой меткой, для результатов заданного поискового запроса или для ответов на любой вопрос. Практически для любой страницы сайта генерируется соответствующий RSS-канал.

Из плюсов стоит заметить настраиваемую частоту обновлений. Скажем, можно задать период обновлений 10 минутам, и получать уведомления о интересных сообщениях гораздо быстрее чем по электронной почте.